# PXSubstitute - CRActivity

Tags: acumatica

I am currently attempting to create a new Activity type that has it's own maintenance screen.

The most logical approach I came up with was to create a new subclass based on CRActivity with the PXSubstitute flag to replace the stock value with mine that has the extra class types in it.

This works for displaying my new class on the screen however whenever I click on any of the items I always receive the message:

```
Error #97: A cache instance cannot be created for the type CRActivity.
```

For reference, here is how i'm defining my new class

```
[CRActivityPrimaryGraph]
[Serializable]
[PXSubstitute()]
[PXCacheName(PX.Objects.CR.Messages.ActivityClassInfo)]
[PXEMailSource]
public partial class CustCRActivity : CRActivity
{
   .....
}
```

I took a step back and tried another approach by doing the same process but for CRPMTimeActivity.   This causes all of the standard Class types to work but my new type gives the same type due to the CRActivityPrimaryGraph not knowing what my new activity type's nagivation is.

Has anyone ever created a new activity type such as this?

Updated 4/28
Below is a screenshot of what I was attempting to accomplish[image]

I did finally get it to work but not quite the way I was hoping.

The initial error message was apparently build specific.  After updating to a newer build that particular error went away.

What I discovered was even though I could Substitute CRActivity, most of the screens themselves were utilizing CRPMTimeActivity which has different attributes associated to it.    CRPMTimeActivity is a subclass of CRActivity and the majority of the processes cast the activity to CRActivity.

A subclass of CRPMTimeActivity cannot be cast as CRActivity.   Because PXSubsitute relies on the base class, this caused casting issues when attempting to add new activities.

In the end I had to create my own custom CRPMTimeActivity class and the base classes then customize the screens themselves to use my version of the activity builders.

The result is shown in the screen shot

Comment: Jeff, could you please provide a couple of screenshots/scratches of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RuslanDev  added a screenshot and updated the information from what I found.   I did get it to work in the end but had to subclass way more than i wanted to simply change the primary graph/display attributes.